Error en validacion con inertia en laravel la peticion devuelve 302
tengo una app con inertia + vue en laravel y tengo el siguiente problema. cuando hago peticiones post y envió todos los datos correctamente no hay problema, la petición termina correctamente. Pero si envió el formulario vacío o algún dato mal, la petición devuelve error 302. Si te quito el request de validación igual pasa la petición. Así que asumo que tengo algo mal en mi validación o con inertia directamente. Acá les dejo mi código
//  **Rutas**

Route::get('/currencies/create', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Currencies/Create');
});

Route::apiResource('currencies', CurrencyController::class);

// **Pagina de Vue**
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Crear Divisa</h1>
        <form @submit.prevent="submit">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Nombre ({{ form.name }})</label>
                <input type="text" v-model="form.name" id="name">
                <span v-if="form.errors.name" class="error">{{ form.errors.name }}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="value">Valor ({{ form.value }})</label>
                <input type="number" v-model="form.value" id="value">
                <span v-if="form.errors.value" class="error">{{ form.errors.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Crear</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                name: '',
                value: '',
                errors: {}
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            Inertia.post('/api/currencies', this.form, {
                onError: (errors) => {
                    this.form.errors = errors;
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
</script>

 //  **Controlador**
 /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(StoreCurrencyRequest $request)
    {
        // Crear una nueva divisa
        $currency = Currency::create($request->validated());

        // Retornar la respuesta
        return response()->json($currency, 201);
    }

// Requests de Validacion
// StoreCurrencyRequest.php

class StoreCurrencyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'value' => ['required', 'numeric'],
        ];
    }
}

Tengo experiencia en laravel, pero recién comienzo con inertia, no se si debo configurar algo más. Saludos y gracias de ante mano

302 no es un header de error sino de redirección. Fíjate en el header de respuesta adónde te está redirigiendo.
